# Unexpected outcomes in if and elif statements

Tags: python

I created a number guessing game and its code is as follows but the problem is that when I input the number which is warm (look at the code)(for eg 70) and then the warmer number(say 69) and then finally the secret number(i.e. 65) instead of showing 'you won!!:)' it again asks the user to input value but if I directly input the secret number or input the secret number followed in any manner accept this one it works fine. I'm new to python so please help in as easy manner as possible.

```
guesses = 0
number = 65
while guesses < 30:
    guess = int(input())
    close = abs(number - guess)
    if guess == number:
        print("You won!!:)")
        break
    elif close < 10:
        print("Warm")
        guesses += 1
        guess = int(input())
        if abs(guess - number) < close:
            print("Warmer")
            guess = int(input())
            guesses += 1
    elif close > 10:
        print("Cold")
        guesses +=1
        if abs(guess - number) < close:
            print("Colder")
            guesses += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `guess = int(input())` from under the `if abs(guess-number) < close:`. The problem was that after `input()` is called there, it is called again at the beginning of the loop on its way to be checked for equality.

```
guesses = 0
number = 65
while guesses<30:
    guess = int(input())
    close = abs(number - guess)
    if guess == number:
        print("You won!!:)")
        break
    elif close<10:
        print("Warm")
        guesses += 1
        guess = int(input())
        if abs(guess-number) < close:
            print("Warmer")
            guesses += 1
    elif close>10:
        print("Cold")
        guesses +=1
        guess = int(input())
        if abs(guess-number)<close:
            print("Colder")
            guesses += 1
```

Comment: Happy to help. If this solution solved your problem, please click the checkmark to the left of my answer so that anyone else knows the question is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It's like that because you ask for a number after `print("Warmer")` and you do nothing with this `guess` - you do not check if it's correct or not. The iteration of loop finishes and it starts again asking for a new guess.

Remove `guess = int(input())` from

```
print("Warmer")
guess = int(input())
guesses += 1
```

and it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

remove             `guess = int(input())` . on line number #15
it's a repeated call for input, because you are calling it on line number #4 which makes it ask for input than give you the result.

Answer (score 0):

The others have pointed out the cause for your specific problem.

I would like to recommend that you should try to avoid code duplication in general. Besides calling `input()` multiple times, you also increment `guesses` at multiple places.

This is so important, it has a cool acronym: *DRY*, which stands for "Don't Repeat Yourself".

Code duplication causes your code to be harder to maintain, because you have to apply the same change in multiple places. *DRY* code, on the other hand, is usually more readable and easier to maintain.

Think about how to rewrite your code to reduce code duplication.